# How to resolve an error uploaded apk is not signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, sha, code-signing-certificate

> `[![Blockquote][1]][1]`
>   [image: Blockquote][image]

When I am uploading my apk to google play it shows an error [sha1 is not matching]

I have uploaded my app with different package names  twice into google play it was successfully uploaded to google play. But when  I update  my app and I changed the package name at third time it shows an error

> **uploaded apk is not signed with the upload certificate**

I am not aware  how to resolve these issue . Please help me out . I need to place my app in play store

Comment: Are you saying that you've changed the package name twice in production?

Comment: Actually app is now in testing mode. yes I have changed the package name

Comment: And what about the signing key used for signed apk? Have you changed that?

Comment: @Harish Jose I did not changed any signing key. Where it locate . How Can I check that

Comment: How did you generated the Apk file. For uploading to playstore you have to choose Build->Generate signed Apk. There you have to select the keystore(.jks file). In most cases we can locate it inside the app directory

Comment: At second pic  at keystorepath I have given my desktop /d15 like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178341/discussion-between-vijju-and-harish-jose).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot upload the next  release of app with different package name.so you need to put the same package name but version code  will be  different.

Comment: first time my package name is com.example.d1, and I uploaded to google play . After I have some changes in my app and again I changed my package name as co.example.d2 it successfully uploaded. Again I have some modifications in functionality of my app and changed the package name as com.example.d3 . Now I am getting an above error. My app is testing mode

Comment: can you please send me the app name

Comment: Now It is not available for all. Only added testers can see app in google play

Comment: You cannot upload the apk with com.example this package  name.If you have uploaded the send me the testing link please.

Comment: I have just given an example name of the package . Just not to reveal the name